# character embedding for arabic language

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, conv-neural-network, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm working on a NLP project (morphological analysis tool for arabic language), that should be able to extract the prefix, root and suffix from an arabic word.

```
sample = {'word': 'الْجِمْعَةَ', 'prefix': 'ال', 'root': 'جمع', 'suffix': 'ة'}
```

This is a sample of the dataset i constructed, the purpose of my model is to extract the prefix, the root and the suffix from an arabic word using a deep neural network. So my intention is to have a word as an input and get the morphemes of my word as output to my neural network.

The way to do so that I thought of is to create 3 character level models, each of them can understand the pattern of prefixes, roots and suffixes and be able to extract them from the word.

If I'm able to  apply character embedding, I'll be able to analyze the patterns of characters and generate the morpheme from the word.

Note : this is how I thought of building the model, it can be completely wrong as I found myself lost at advancing in this project,  any help would be appreciated as for suggesting the correct structure or recommending better resources.